# Alternative to service broker for webapi calls

Tags: sql, webapi, maui

I made an app a few years ago which used sqlserver and service broker to update the display when the data in the db was updated .

Not really a fan of service broker, that is we a pain in its own right. But it did eventually work.

Now though I’m trying to port everything to MAUI, mainly so I can target android and windows.

However I have a problem. It seems advisable not to use sql connections direct in Maui code for some reason. So I have set up a webapi to handle this and pass the data back as a Json string.

So using this method I can’t see any way to know when the database has changed.

Is it just a matter of polling the db? Or is there a more elegant solution?

Thank you

Andrew

Comment: You can use gRPC or SignalR to actively notify clients of updates, but that can be expensive and complex.  I would personally try polling

Comment: Could you provide some code related ?